# Spring boot + hibernate - save a descendant from an abstract object

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I can't save the object to the database.

```
@Entity
public abstract class Participant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable=false)
    private Participant parent;

    private String surname;

    private String name;

    private String patronymic;

    private String birthday;

    private String address;

    private int age;

....
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agreements_participant_child")
public class ParticipantChild extends Participant{
    private String certSerial;
    private String certNumber;
    private String certIssuedDate;
    private String certIssuedBy;
...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agreements_participants")
public class Participants {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    ParticipantAdult mother;
    @OneToOne
    ParticipantAdult father;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    ArrayList<Participant> children;
```

I get an error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag] : `ru.thebestsoft.lawtreaty3.employees.participants.Participants.children` (setter)] with root cause
```

I understand that the problem is inheritance from an abstract class and I need to tell hibernate that the class is abstract, but I don't know how.

Comment: Have you mapped the table properly in your Entity Class through spring annotation??

Comment: If you try to annotate `Participant` class with `MappedSuperclass` instead of `Entity` something changes?

Comment: Does not give - Many To One attribute type should not be Mapped Superclass

Comment: Considering that further search by participants is unlikely, I decided to just save this ArrayList in JSON. Everything is working properly. In the end, I came to the conclusion that the problem arises precisely when working with collections. I tried to link them two-way, and put them into different tables and into one, but the result is still negative.

Comment: @dariosicily, you can't do that with arraylist